# Validating an email with an onblur event in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, validation, email

How do I validate an email in JavaScript. I have click event that checks if the value is blank - please see below but how do I check an onblur event in a separate function that checks an regular expression

```
var e =document.forms["myForm"]["email_18"].value;
if(e==null ||e=="" || e=="someone@example.com")
{
    document.getElementById("emailMessage").innerHTML = "*Please enter an  email";
    flag = false;
}
```

Text Box:

```
<input type="email" class="text" name="email_18" id="amf-input-email_18" value="" placeholder="someone@example.com" maxlength="255" onkeyup="if(this.length>255) this.value=this.value.substr(0, 255)"></div></div>
```

Comment: So what do you want to know? How to use a regex or how to use an onblur event?

Comment: Both, so how to do a regex to validate an email address and then add an oblur event handler or listener.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript duplicate maybe

Comment: You use onkeyup in your code ... why not onblur too?

Comment: It was dynamically created so I didn't use the onkeyup event it was just given to me like that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use regex for email checking:

```
function checkEmail(str)
{
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    if(!re.test(str))
    alert("Please enter a valid email address");
}
```

add onblur event to your input box:

```
<input type="email" class="text" name="email_18" id="amf-input-email_18" value="" placeholder="someone@example.com" maxlength="255" onblur="checkEmail(this.value)"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set onblur atrribute of yout textbox to function name as below

```
<input type="email" class="text" name="email_18" id="amf-input-email_18" value="" placeholder="someone@example.com" maxlength="255" onkeyup="if(this.length>255) this.value=this.value.substr(0, 255)" onblur="checkemail(this.value)">
```

And write the javascript function as below :

```
function checkemail(email)
{
   var regex=/^[a-zA-Z0-9\.\_]+\@@{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.\w{2,4}$/;
   if(!regex.test(email))
   {
       alert('Please enter valid email id');
    }
 }
```